# Trying to get property of non-object in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, properties

I have s function in my wordpress `function.php` file that should exclude pages by slug instead of ID. Now it works fine, but in some cases it causes: Trying to get property of non-object in `/Users/kailoon/Sites/wordpress/wp-content/themes/ebookie-wp/functions.php` on line 128 the line that says:

```
array_push($ids, $page->ID)
```

The problem is that I cannot reproduce this error on my own localhost. Full code of this function is like this. Can someone please help?

```
function exclude_by_slug($slugs){
    $slugs = preg_split("/,s?/", $slugs);
    $ids = array();

    foreach($slugs as $page_slug){
        $page = get_page_by_path($page_slug);
        array_push($ids, $page->ID);
    }
    return implode(",", $ids);
}
```

Comment: Debug what the value of var $page_slug everytime in the loop to see what is the value.

Answer (score 0):

That error means that at times, `get_page_by_path` isn't getting a page and therefore `$page` is null. You need to test to make sure it isn't null before trying to get its ID and push it.

Your split regexp is suspicious: you're splitting on a comma followed by an optional lower-case 's'. Are you sure you don't mean '\s'? If that's actually in your code, that would strip the 's' off any slug that starts with it, which would cause `get_page_by_path` to fail on it.